# What is the function of NSRange

Tags: swift, foundation, nsrange

I am confused regarding the functionality of NSRange.

What is the function of NSRange in this code?

```
shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange
```

Comment: Have you tried Googling this?

Comment: It's clearly explained in the [reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield?language=objc) for the method.

Answer (score 1):

`Foundation` is an *old* pre-Swift framework. It's mostly written in Objective-C and uses its types. `NSRange` is a C struct heavily used in Objective-C in conjunction with `NSString`.

`NSString` is converted to Swift as `String` and most methods using `NSRange` has been converted to methods using `Range` (or other Swift types). However, in some methods the Objective-C type still exists for various compatibility reasons. `UITextViewDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate` are prime examples.

To properly use `NSRange` you should convert `String` to a `NSString` first, e.g.:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText: String) -> Bool
    let previousText = (textView.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newText = previousText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacementText)

   ...
}
```

In this method the `range` describes the range of string that is being changed. Its `locations` tells you where the new text is being put and its `length` tells you how much of previous text is being replaced/removed.

For example a `NSRange(location: 2, length: 1)` with `replacementText: ""` tells you that the third character is being removed (e.g. when backspace is pressed).